# React application on production - links don't work when requested directly, they work only when accessed by react router

Tags: reactjs, linux, apache, nginx

I have deployed an application on a ubuntu server.
I ran `npm run build`, and copied all the content of build inside /var/www/html
The file **/etc/nginx/sites-available/default** looks like that (default value):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.html;
    server_name _;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

When trying to access 111.111.11.11/contact-us directly with the browser, I get a 404. What am I missing? why doesn't the react app handle that request?

Here is some code:

History.js:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();
```

App.js:

```
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
render() {
        return (
          <div className="page">
            <Router history={history}>
            <Header />
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/combination/:uniqueUrl" exact component={CombinationPage} />
                <Route path="/" exact component={MainContent} />
                <Route path="/contact-us" exact component={ContactUs} />
                <Route path="*" exact component={PageNotFound} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
          </div>
        )
      }
```

**Important update**: If I add a **/#/**, it's working and I can access the page. For example http://111.111.11.11/#/contact-us.

**Important information:** Locally it's working correctly when using `"npm run start"` the problem is when it's on the ubuntu server, after running `npm run build`.

Comment: Put `"homepage": ".",` in your `package.json`. Also, try with `HashRouter`.

Comment: Thanks, interesting direction. it's not working, but it's adding a /#/ at the end of the url. If I add /#/contact-us after the domain (ip) it does work, and i have access to the page

Comment: If you want to remove this hash, `import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';` and `<Router history={browserHistory}>`. If it's what you asked for, I can make it a proper answer.

Comment: I'm already using browserHistory. I have one file containing only import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
export default createBrowserHistory();   that's it. and my router does <Router history={history}>

Comment: @k-wasilewski any idea? :/

Comment: Ok, back to basics: did you wrap your `index.js` in `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: @k-wasilewski No, should I? Is it even possible? Please notice the important information I added (last sentence)

Comment: So what build tool did you use? `create-react-app`?

Comment: yes, but I don't see any example where the router is implemented in index.js. @k-wasilewski

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i know, I am replying a long time later, but today I had the same error, I solved it by editing the nginx config file

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

I hope that it would be useful to someone